# Is there any way to crawl dynamic website without library?

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, axios, web-crawler

I'm using 'axios' to crawl data from web sites(https://movie.daum.net/premovie/released)

I need data of li tags under ol tag, but li tags aren't shown in source.

[element tab in dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z5UsJ.png)

[source tab in dev tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WC5D.png)

I guess the site renders li tags dynamically using JavaScript or etc., but I don't know how to crawl them after all tags are loaded.

The point is, I wanna do it without any library related to crawling like puppeteer.

Please let me know how to do it if you know it. Thank you.

==============

Found the way to solve it!

[[웹 크롤링] JavaScript로 된 html 불러오기](https://sodayeong.tistory.com/16)

It is written in Korean, but was really helpful.

Comment: If you are looking to load all the movies as you scroll down the page could you look at the network tab of the browser and call their API and just load the data that way?

Comment: @AranMulholland Yeah I found the way of checking the network tab and use XHR Files! Thank you for your answering.

Comment: If you have found a solution, you should put the solution in an answer, explain it in English and mark the question as answered by yourself so others can use the knowledge in the future and the question does not remain unanswered forever.

Comment: Isn't axios a library?

Comment: @AranMulholland Thx! I didn't know how to mark the question as answered. Thank you for your sharing knowledge.

Comment: @trincot Yeah it is, I know. I meant the library directly 'related to crawling' like Selenium, puppeteer.

Comment: @KyeolHan you may not have enough credit points to mark the answer as accepted if you answer it yourself. But usually there is a tick at the top left of the answer you click on to mark it as correct.

Comment: @AranMulholland So kind! I found it. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Please see my comment on your accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way to solve it!

For my case, I found the XHR exists in network tab of dev tools.
So I requested the 'get' axios method to XHR url, not the url of web page.

[XHR tab in dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGpRy.png)

[[웹 크롤링] JavaScript로 된 html 불러오기](https://sodayeong.tistory.com/16)

I found it in here!
It is written in Korean, but was really helpful.

Comment: One thing we really recommend on stack overflow is to get the answer from the website where you found your answer and write a summary in the answer here so people do not have to follow a link that may disappear over time so even if the answer on the site goes down we have the answer here. If you don't have enough credit points here to edit your answer write another one and make it the answer so people can find the answer here without browsing to another site. That way the answer is here for anyone that needs it in the future.

Comment: @AranMulholland Thank you for your helping! I added the image of XHR existing in dev tools.